# Why can I sometimes prove a goal via a lemma, but not directly?

Tags: coq

Consider the function defined below. It's not really important what it does.

```
Require Import Ring.
Require Import Vector.
Require Import ArithRing.

Fixpoint
  ScatHUnion_0 {A} (n:nat) (pad:nat) : t A n -> t (option A) ((S pad) * n).
 refine (
  match n return (t A n) -> (t (option A) ((S pad)*n)) with
  | 0 => fun _ =>  (fun H => _)(@nil (option A))
  | S p =>
    fun a =>
      let foo := (@ScatHUnion_0 A p pad (tl a)) in
      (fun H => _) (cons _ (Some (hd a)) _ (append (const None pad) foo))
  end
   ).
 rewrite  <-(mult_n_O (S pad)); auto.
 replace  (S pad * S p) with ( (S (pad + S pad * p)) ); auto; ring.
Defined.
```

I want to prove

```
Lemma test0:  @ScatHUnion_0 nat 0 0 ( @nil nat) = ( @nil (option nat)).
```

After doing

```
  simpl. unfold eq_rect_r. unfold eq_rect.
```

the goal is

```
         match mult_n_O 1 in (_ = y) return (t (option nat) y) with
         | eq_refl => nil (option nat)
         end = nil (option nat)
```

When trying to finish it off with

```
  apply trans_eq with (Vector.const (@None nat) (1 * 0)); auto.
  destruct (mult_n_O 1); auto.
```

the `destruct` doesn't work (see below for error message).  However, If I first prove exactly the same goal in a lemma or even with `assert` inside the proof, I can apply and solve it, like this:

```
Lemma test1:  @ScatHUnion_0 nat 0 0 ( @nil nat) = ( @nil (option nat)).
  simpl. unfold eq_rect_r. unfold eq_rect.

  assert (
      match mult_n_O 1 in (_ = y) return (t (option nat) y) with
        | eq_refl => nil (option nat)
      end = nil (option nat)
    ) as H.
  {
    apply trans_eq with (Vector.const (@None nat) (1 * 0)); auto.
    destruct (mult_n_O 1); auto.
  }
    apply H.
Qed.
```

Can someone explain why this is, and how one should think about this situation when one encounters it?

---

In Coq 8.4 I get the error

```
      Toplevel input, characters 0-21:
      Error: Abstracting over the terms "n" and "e" leads to a term
      "fun (n : nat) (e : 0 = n) =>
       match e in (_ = y) return (t (option nat) y) with
       | eq_refl => nil (option nat)
       end = const None n" which is ill-typed.
```

and in Coq 8.5 I get the error

```
      Error: Abstracting over the terms "n" and "e" leads to a term
      fun (n0 : nat) (e0 : 0 = n0) =>
      match e0 in (_ = y) return (t (option nat) y) with
      | eq_refl => nil (option nat)
      end = const None n0
      which is ill-typed.
      Reason is: Illegal application: 
      The term "@eq" of type "forall A : Type, A -> A -> Prop"
      cannot be applied to the terms
       "t (option nat) 0" : "Set"
       "match e0 in (_ = y) return (t (option nat) y) with
        | eq_refl => nil (option nat)
        end" : "t (option nat) n0"
       "const None n0" : "t (option nat) n0"
      The 2nd term has type "t (option nat) n0" which should be coercible to
       "t (option nat) 0".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would said it's because of dependent types, and you don't actually prove the exact same things in both case (try to `Set Printing All.` to see implicit types and hidden information).

The fact that such a destruct fails is often due to the fact that the dependency will introduce a ill-typed term at, and you have to be more precise in what you want to destruct (no secret here, its on a per case basis). By extracting a sub-lemma, you might have remove the troublesome dependency, and now the destruct can operate.

Answer (score 2):

@Vinz answer explained the reason, and suggested `Set Printing All.` which shows what the difference is.  The problem was that `simpl.` simplified the return type of the `match`.  Using `unfold ScatHUnion_0.` instead of `simpl.` enabled me to use the destruct directly on the goal.

Fundamentally, my troubles stemmed from me wanting to convince the type system that `0=0` is the same as `0=1*0`.  (Btw, I still don't know the best way to do this.) I was using `mult_n_O` to show that, but it is opaque, so the type system couldn't unfold it when checking that the two types were equal.

When I replaced it with my own `Fixpoint` variant (which is not opaque),

```
Fixpoint mult_n_O n: 0 = n*0 :=
    match n as n0 return (0 = n0 * 0) with
  | 0 => eq_refl
  | S n' => mult_n_O n'
  end.
```

and used it in the definition of `ScatHUnion_0`, the lemma was trivial to prove:

```
Lemma test0:  @ScatHUnion_0 nat 0 0 ( @nil nat) = ( @nil (option nat)).
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

---

Additional comment:

Here is a proof that works with the original opaque `mult_n_O` definition. It is based on a [proof by Jason Gross](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2015-05/msg00176.html). 
It manipulates the type of `mult_n_O 1` to be `0=0` by using `generalize`. It uses `set` to modify the term's implicit parts, such as the type in `eq_refl`, which is only visible after the `Set Printing All.` command. `change` can also do that, but `replace` and `rewrite` don't seem to be able to do that.

```
Lemma test02:
  match mult_n_O 1 in (_ = y) return (t (option nat) y) with
    | eq_refl => nil (option nat)
  end = nil (option nat).
Proof.
  Set Printing All.
  generalize (mult_n_O 1 : 0=0).
  simpl.
  set (z:=0) at 2 3.
  change (nil (option nat)) with (const (@None nat) z) at 2.
  destruct e.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

---

Update:  Here is an even simpler proof thanks to the people at coq-club.

```
Lemma test03:
  match mult_n_O 1 in (_ = y) return (t (option nat) y) with
    | eq_refl => nil (option nat)
  end = nil (option nat).
Proof.
  replace (mult_n_O 1) with (@eq_refl nat 0);
  auto using Peano_dec.UIP_nat.
Qed.
```

Comment: You don't have to convince Coq that ``0 = 1 * 0``, it is perfectly true (just prove it by ``reflexivity``). The problem in your case is after your ``simpl``, you end up inspecting a *proof* of that fact, namely ``mult_n_0 1``, which is opaque. Coq unfolding rules require a non-opaque term to be able to go through a ``match`` statement. This is why simpl is stuck at the ``eq_rect_t`` stage and does not unfold more. By making this proof ``Defined``, you remove this problem and the simplification can go on (that's why ``reflexivity`` works in the end).

Comment: Yes,  but how do I convince the type checker to use reflexivity?

Comment: I just saw your question on the coq-club mailing list and I might have miss-understood the issue: ``0 = 1 * 0`` is proved trivially by reflexivity, but ``forall P1 P2: 0 = 1 * 0, P1 = P2``, meaning "for any two proofs of this fact, the *proofs* are equal", than you can't do it so trivially, you need a property (true on nat) called "Uniqueness of Identity Proof"; In Coq, proofs of a same equality statement are not necessarily equal. But it's true at least for proof of equality on types which are decidable.